# WSDL Output to PHP var?

Tags: php, xml, wsdl

I get this output from a WSDL Source.
Now i would like to save all part in a PHP variable.
But how can i split this big thing? foreach? any idea?
I would like to have all information in different variables.

All data in the $response..

```
$response = $client->getAllEventInfos('12345');
print_r($response);
```

And thats the output...

```
stdClass Object ( 
[beautifulDate] => 01.05.2018 20:00 - 21:00 
[concernedPersons] => Array ( 
[0] => stdClass Object ( 
    [item] => Array ( 
        [0] => John Doe 
        [1] => Vortragender 
        [2] => ) ) ) 
[eventPool] => stdClass Object ( 
    [id] => 1 
    [institutionName] => ASM Rechnungen 
    [name] => ASM ) 
    [eventdates] => Array ( 
        [0] => stdClass Object ( 
            [item] => Array ( 
                [0] => 01.05.2018 von 20:00 bis 21:00 
                [1] => Zwettl 
                [2] => 01.05.2018 20:00 
                [3] => 01.05.2018 21:00 ) ) ) 
[fullyBooked] => 
[id] => 10011 
[name] => Besuch des Präsidenten 
[registrationEndDate] => 25.12.2018 
[registrationLink] => https:example.com 
[registrationStartDate] => 01.01.2018 
[startDate] => 01.05.2018 
[wsEventDates] => Array ( 
    [0] => stdClass Object ( 
        [beginTime] => 01.05.2018 20:00 
        [endTime] => 01.05.2018 21:00 
        [periode] => 01.05.2018 von 20:00 bis 21:00 
        [venueName] => Zwettl ) ) 
[iCalLink] => https://example.com )
```

Comment: Why do you need to do so? It's already accessible now, and can be used straight away.  example echo $response->beautifulDate;

Comment: and whats about "concernedPersons" ! how can i get john doe, for example?

Answer (score 0):

This is a response from your comment

loop the concernedPersons array like:

```
foreach($response->concernedPersons as $person) {
      foreach($person->item as $item){
            echo $item."<br>";
      }

}
```